# Mock service worker on node post and grapql.query not working

Tags: node.js, rest, graphql, msw

I have a node app that uses a library to make a graphql query after it authenticated. The following graphql query does not pick up the request:

```
  graphql.query(/^(.+?)$/, (req, res, ctx) => {
    console.log('keys:', Object.keys(req))
    console.log('query:', req.query)
    console.log('variables', req.variables)
    return res(
      ctx.data({
        data: [],
      })
    )
  }),
```

Tried many combinations but `/^(.+?)$/` should pick up anything. When adding the following:

```
  rest.post('*', (req, res, ctx) => {
    console.log('POST ALL', req.url.pathname)
    if (req.url.pathname === '/oauth/token') {
      return res(
        ctx.status(200),
        ctx.json({
          valid:'token'
        })
      )
    }
    return req.json().then((body) => {
      console.log('body:', body)
      console.log('pass through')
      return req.passthrough()
    })
  }),
```

It logs the following:

```
POST ALL /oauth/token
POST ALL /project/graphql
    body: {
      operationName: 'ProductTypeId',
      query: '\n' +
        '    query fetchProductTypeId($where: String) {\n' +
        '      productTypes(where: $where, limit: 1) {\n' +
        '        results {\n' +
        '          id\n' +
        '        }\n' +
        '      }\n' +
        '    }\n' +
        '  ',
      variables: { where: 'key="typeKey"' }
    }
pass through
```

But when trying handlers:

```
  graphql.query(/^(.+?)$/, (req, res, ctx) => {
    console.log('keys:', Object.keys(req))
    console.log('query:', req.query)
    console.log('variables', req.variables)
    return res(
      ctx.data({
        data: [],
      })
    )
  }),
  rest.post('*/oauth/token', (req, res, ctx) => {
    log('POST', req.url.pathname)
    if (req.url.pathname === '/oauth/token') {
      return res(
        ctx.status(200),
        ctx.json({
          valid:'token'
        })
      )
    }
    log('pass through')
    return req.passthrough()
  }),
```

The token request handler is used but then the library makes the graphql request and the graphql handler is never used and instead I get:

```
[MSW] Warning: captured a request without a matching request handler:

  • POST https://server/project/graphql

If you still wish to intercept this unhandled request, please create a request handler for it.
Read more: https://mswjs.io/docs/getting-started/mocks
```

Nice of msw to tell me but the handler is obviously there. Tried `graphql.query('ProductTypeId'` and `graphql.query('fetchProductTypeId'` but same result. Looks like having rest.post and and graphql.query handler breaks the graphql even though the post only picks up the authentication.

**update**

Removed all the handlers except the graphql and provided valid credentials to create a token. So the only handler I have is:

```
  graphql.query('fetchProductTypeId', (req, res, ctx) => {
    console.log('keys:', Object.keys(req))
    console.log('query:', req.query)
    console.log('variables', req.variables)
    return res(
      ctx.data({
        data: [],
      })
    )
  }),
```

Then in start server I have:

```
  server.listen({
    onUnhandledRequest: (req) => {
      console.log('unhandled')
      console.log('path:::', req.url.pathname)
      req
        .json()
        .then((body) => {
          console.log('body:::', body)
        })
        .catch((e) => e)
    },
  })
```

This will log:

```
unhandled
path::: /project/graphql
    body::: {
      query: 'query fetchProductTypeId($where: String) {\n' +
        '      productTypes(where: $where, limit: 1) {\n' +
        '        results {\n' +
        '          id\n' +
        '        }\n' +
        '      }\n' +
        '    }\n' +
        '  ',
      operationName: 'fetchProductTypeId',
      variables: { where: 'key="key"' }
    }
```

Maybe graphql is just completely broken in the version of msw I happened to have installed (version 0.47.4)

And `graphql.query(/^(.+?)$/` does the same thing, that handler may as well not be there at all.

** Update

I see that `graphql.operation((req, res, ctx)` as a handler isn't getting called either so msw must just not understand that my graphql request is not a graphql request even though body is logged and is obviously a graphql request.

Just created an [issue](https://github.com/mswjs/msw/issues/1471)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see the library I use created a header `'Content-Type': 'application/graphql',` seems fine according to a quick read [here](https://graphql.org/learn/serving-over-http/) but when I change it to `'Content-Type': 'application/json'` (library allows me to add headers) it will be picked up by the handler.